# Сортировка массива php c Городами

Tags: php, массивы

на выхлопе есть массив с городами , отсортированный в алфавитном порядке.
Необходимо Москву и Питер поставить первыми, а далее также в алфавитном порядке
Побывал сдвинуть ключи массива, и поменять  Москве и Питеру  на 01 и 02. Но чего-то не выходит.
Подскажите пожалуйста правильный алгоритм, как решить эту задачу
Заранее спасибо

```
array(4) {
[0]=> array(8) {
    ["CITY"]=>
    string(18) "Волгоград"

}
[1]=> array(8) {
    ["CITY"]=>
    string(18) "Ростов-на-Дону"

}
[2]=> array(8) {
    ["CITY"]=>
    string(18) "Казань"

}
[3]=> array(8) {
    ["CITY"]=>
    string(18) "Москва"

}
[4]=> array(8) {
    ["CITY"]=>
    string(18) "Санкт-Петербург"

}
[5]=> array(8) {
    ["CITY"]=>
    string(18) "уфа"

}}
```

Или как правильно при переборке масива foreach менять ключи у Москвы и Питера, и ставить их выше других

Answer (score 0):

Коряво получилось, но работает ))

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    foreach ($array[$i] as $key=>$value){
       if ($key == 'CITY' && $value == 'Москва' || $value == 'Санкт-Петербург'){
         $array2[] = $array[$i];
         unset($array[$i]);
       }
     }
   }

  foreach ($array2 as $city){
    array_unshift($array, $city);
  }

    var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать пользовательскую сортировку [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php).
Вот пример:

```
$ar_sort = [
    100 =>'Москва',
    50 => 'Санкт-Петербург'
];

usort($array, function($a, $b) use($ar_sort) {
    $a_key = array_search($a['CITY'], $ar_sort);
    $b_key = array_search($b['CITY'], $ar_sort);

    if($a_key > $b_key) {
        return -1;
    } else if($a_key < $b_key) {
        return 1;
    } else if($a['CITY'] > $b['CITY']) {
        return 1;
    } else if($a['CITY'] < $b['CITY']) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

То есть идея простая: Имеем массив сортировки **$ar_sort**. Сначала ищем вхождение в него и сравниваем результат, а уже после сравниваем как обычные строки.

Answer (score 0):

Можно удалить Москву и Питер, а затем добавить их в начало массива.

```
function capitals($item){
    return in_array($item['CITY'], ['Москва', 'Санкт-Петербург']);
}

function not_capitals($item){
    return !capitals($item);
}

$arr = [ваш массив с городами];

$capitals = array_filter($arr, "capitals"); // Столицы
$notCapit = array_filter($arr, "not_capitals"); // Остальные города

// результирующий массив, где москва и питер в начале
$result = array_merge($capitals, $notCapit);
```